# Filtering items using drop down list

Tags: python, django

Would like to filter features(products) by using dropdown menu. Each of the feature(product) got a tag (e.g. food, drink, random). Idea is when user selects the tag on a menu, it shows only those items who's got that tag.
So far I went as far, but doesn't seem to work yet. PyCharm does not give an error, but not functioning. What I am missing? Thank you!

my models.py

```
class Feature(models.Model):
FOOD = 'food'
DRINK = 'drink'
RANDOM = 'random'
TAGS = (
    (FOOD, 'food'),
    (DRINK, 'drink'),
    (RANDOM, 'random')
)
name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='')
tags = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TAGS, default=ALL)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

my views.py

```
def tags(request):
if request.GET.get('tags'):
    features_filter = request.GET.get('tags')
    listings = Feature.objects.filter(features_filter=features_filter)
else:
    listings = Feature.objects.all()

context = {'listings': listings}
return render(request, 'index', context)
```

my index.html

```
<form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
{% csrf_token %}
 <select name="tags">
     {% for feat in features %}
        <option value="{{feat.tags}}">{{ feat.tags }}</option>
     {% endfor %}
 </select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>


{% for feature in features %}            
  <h1{{ feature.name }}</strong></h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this

> ```
> listings = Feature.objects.filter(features_filter=features_filter)
> ```

to

```
listings = Feature.objects.filter(tags=features_filter)
```